# Canvas renders View, Console gives right output, but View in app stays empty

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

On MacOS, I have a very simple `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var environment: Environment
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let glyph = environment.glyph {
            print ("Content View \(glyph)")
            return AnyView {
                GlyphView(glyph: glyph)
            }
        } else {
            return AnyView {
                Text("no glyph")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var environment = Environment()
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(environment: environment)
    }
}
```

When I run application, console gives:

```
2020-10-14 21:50:42.065365+0200 ShapeSearch[94679:5992139] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-10-14 21:50:42.093298+0200 ShapeSearch[94679:5992191] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
2020-10-14 21:50:42.093688+0200 ShapeSearch[94679:5992191] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
Content View Glyph "k" - 6 contours
```

and `ContentView` stays empty, no `GlyphView`, no `Text`.

But when I debug `GlyphView`, I can see very nice rendered glyph on canvas:

```
struct GlyphView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var glyph = Environment().glyph!
    static var previews: some View {
        GlyphView(glyph: glyph)
    }
}
```

`environment.glyph` is taken from the same source in both cases. I'm sure.

**Edit:**

This way it works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var environment: Environment
    
    var body: some View {
        GlyphView(glyph: environment.glyph!)
    }
}
```

Where a mistake could be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear which SwiftUI version do you use, but the following should work in any case

```
var body: some View {
  Group {  
    if nil != environment.glyph {
        GlyphView(glyph: environment.glyph!)
    } else {
        Text("no glyph")
    }
  }
}
```